# Ruby gem tab completion on zsh produces "doubled rest argument definition" error?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zsh

When I hit `gem push <tab>`, it displays this error (regardless of whether the directory contains any `.gem` files):

```
_arguments:comparguments:325: doubled rest argument definition: *:gem:_files -g "*.gem(-.)"
_arguments:comparguments:325: doubled rest argument definition: *:gem:_files -g "*.gem(-.)"
_arguments:comparguments:325: doubled rest argument definition: *:gem:_files -g "*.gem(-.)"
```

I have no idea how to fix this and Google is no help. My `fpath`:

```
> echo $fpath
/Users/robenkleene/.zsh/completion
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.7/share/zsh/functions
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installed Ruby via homebrew because the above "Cellar" path contains a `_gem` file that I believe defines this completion function, but that didn't work.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

(Also, if anyone has any suggestions of where I might file a bug report for this that would also be helpful, thanks again!)

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together my own terrible solution to this but it's better than nothing.

I copied the `_gem` file from `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.7/share/zsh/functions` to `/Users/robenkleene/.zsh/completion` and then modified the offending line (note that this only works because I have `fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)` in my `zshrc`):

```
-      args+=( '*:gem:_files -g "*.gem(-.)"' )
+      args=( '*:gem:_files -g "*.gem(-.)"' )
```

So I removed the `+`. This seems to work, but I'd love a more elegant solution and/or any information about why (based on my Google search), I seem to be the only person experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macOS 10.15.6 running the default zsh 5.7.1. In the default zsh gem completion I found that `push` is being included in a list of commands which take a remote gem name — and it shouldn't be, it only takes the path to the gem file:

```sh
$ gem push --help                                                      
Usage: gem push GEM [options]
```

I applied the following patch to a copy of the file higher in `$fpath` and it now works for me:

```
--- /usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions/_gem
+++ ~/.zsh/completion.d/_gem
@@ -56,7 +56,7 @@
     check|cleanup|contents|dependency|list|open|pristine|rdoc|uninstall|unpack|update)
       args+=( '(--all --skip)*:installed gem:->gems-local' )
     ;|
-    fetch|install|lock|owner|push|search|yank)
+    fetch|install|lock|owner|search|yank)
       args+=( '*:gem:->gems-remote' )
     ;|
     cleanup|uninstall)
```

I'm not sure where to contribute this patch.